# Unit test Tensorflow Transform operations

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to do unit test on my functions that contains Tensorflow Transform operations. Something like this:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("inputs,expected_result",
    [(
        tf.linspace(start=0, stop=10, num=10),
        tf.linspace(start=0, stop=1, num=10),
    )]
)
def test_tft_scale(inputs, expected_result):
    out = tft.scale_to_0_1(inputs)
    assert tf.experimental.numpy.allclose(out, expected_result)
```

I got error related to eager execution:

```
RuntimeError: tf.placeholder() is not compatible with eager execution
```

I tried disabling eager execution by putting `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()` but I got another error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate this function with @tf.function.
```

How to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So you are trying to convert Python eager code into graph-compatible TensorFlow ops which you can do so using the `AutoGraph` library. You can use this by simply adding in the `@tf.function` decorator and chaining it with your `@pytest.mark.parametrize()` decorator. `@tf.function` uses `AutoGraph` by default and you can read more about it [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#autograph_transformations).

#### Edit:

I think you are better off using `tf.test.TestCase` like so, with the removal of using `tft.scale_to_0_1()` as you can just scale the tensors to a range of 0 to 1 using `tensor = tensor / tf.norm(tensor)`. You would not need to enable `tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()` with this.

```
import tensorflow as tf

class TFTScaleTest(tf.test.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        super(TFTScaleTest, self).setUp()
        self.input = tf.linspace(start=0, stop=10, num=10)
        self.expected_result = tf.linspace(start=0, stop=1, num=10)

    def test_tft_scale(self):
        tensor = tf.cast(self.input, dtype=tf.float64)
        tensor = tensor / tf.norm(tensor)
        self.assertAllClose(tensor, self.expected_result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tf.test.main()
```

#### Test case results:

```
AssertionError: 
Not equal to tolerance rtol=1e-06, atol=1e-06
Mismatched value: a is different from b. 
not close where = (array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),)
not close lhs = [0.05923489 0.11846978 0.17770466 0.23693955 0.29617444 0.35540933
 0.41464421 0.4738791  0.53311399]
not close rhs = [0.11111111 0.22222222 0.33333333 0.44444444 0.55555556 0.66666667
 0.77777778 0.88888889 1.        ]
not close dif = [0.05187622 0.10375245 0.15562867 0.20750489 0.25938112 0.31125734
 0.36313356 0.41500979 0.46688601]
not close tol = [1.11111111e-06 1.22222222e-06 1.33333333e-06 1.44444444e-06
 1.55555556e-06 1.66666667e-06 1.77777778e-06 1.88888889e-06
 2.00000000e-06]
dtype = float64, shape = (10,)
Mismatched elements: 9 / 10 (90%)
Max absolute difference: 0.46688601
Max relative difference: 0.46688601
 x: array([0.      , 0.059235, 0.11847 , 0.177705, 0.23694 , 0.296174,
       0.355409, 0.414644, 0.473879, 0.533114])
 y: array([0.      , 0.111111, 0.222222, 0.333333, 0.444444, 0.555556,
       0.666667, 0.777778, 0.888889, 1.      ])
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I got following error: ```OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.

../env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py:977: OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError```

Comment: @eng2019 I fixed the issue its an assertion issue, but I am not sure whether the expected result is supposed to be True or False.

Comment: After I checked, the problem is after the operation of ```tft.scale_to_0_1```, ```out == <tf.Tensor 'scale_to_0_1/add_1:0' shape=(10,) dtype=float32>``` while ```expected_result == <tf.Tensor 'expected_result:0' shape=(10,) dtype=float64>``` which cause the assertion to fail

Comment: Yes that is correct. I tried it in numpy and it returns `False`.

Comment: What I don't get is how can I evaluate the value of those tensors ```out``` and ```expected_result``` since I can't run ```tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()``` after the operations?

Comment: @eng2019 could you check the updated answer using `tf.test.TestCase` instead of pytest? I am not sure if pytest is appropriate for this.